# Query with global secondary index taking 800ms for 5000 items, normal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table with 5000 items in it. When querying using a Global Secondary Index, the query is taking approximately 800ms to return. This is using a Lambda on the same region as the table.

Is this normal and expected?

The code I am running looks as follows:

```
const queryCommandInput: QueryCommandInput = {
  TableName: 'Table',
  IndexName: 'index',
  KeyConditionExpression: 'id = :id',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':id': 'myId' }
}

let foundItems: JourneysTableItem[] = []

try {
  const output = await documentClient.send(new QueryCommand(queryCommandInput))

  foundItems = output.Items as JourneysTableItem[]
      
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}

return foundItems
```

Comment: we need more details - what does the query look like and how many items are being returned?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari Approx 5000 items are being returned out of ~8000.

Comment: Interesting. It looks like that one query is returning all the results? So no pagination involved?

Comment: Hi @MariaInesParnisari no pagination involved - is the time therefore expected?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari can I do any optimisations or how would I implement pagination?

Comment: It sounds strange that just 1 request takes 800 ms. What happens if you run that request multiple times, what average and what p50 do you get?

Comment: Also, maybe you are making a cross-region call. Which endpoint are you calling and where is your client running?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it seems normal and expected. DynamoDB offers single digit millisecond response times for singleton requestes, i.e GetItem for an item < 4KB or PutItem for an item > 1KB.

On top of you requesting 5000 items, you must also consider the full network round trip, including client initialization and TCP handshakes etc...